# How to append a string to the left of a match only when the match is found?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression for an .Net UrlRewriter and I need to append the rest of the query string to the new url together with the '?' character only when the query string exists.
Some examples:

```
/products/product.asp?func=show&id=1
becomes
/product/1.asp

/products/product.asp?func=show&id=1&sid=2&utm_medium=none
becomes
/product/1.asp?sid=2&utm_medium=none
```

I managed to build an expression, but I'm having problems on appending the extra values form the query string, actually with the fact that when there are no other query string values I don't want to use the "?" character, I want to trim it from the end.

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^/products/product\.asp\?(?:func=show&)?id=(?<id>\d+)(&(?<tail>.+))?$");


var urls = new []
    { 
        "/products/product.asp?func=show&id=34123&sid=1&bit=2&utm_medium=etc",
        "/products/product.asp?func=show&id=34123&sid=1",
        "/products/product.asp?func=show&id=34123",
        "/products/product.asp?id=34123",           
    };

urls.Select(url=> reg.Replace(url,"/product/${id}.asp?${tail}"))
    .Dump();
```

This outputs

```
/product/34123.asp?sid=1&bit=2&utm_medium=etc 
/product/34123.asp?sid=1 
/product/34123.asp? 
/product/34123.asp?
```

I need to trim '?' from the query.

Solutions like TrimEnd('?') are not accepted because the rewriting module works with regular expressions and I don't want to override it only for a Trim() call.

The expression **`"^/products/product\.asp\?(?:func=show&)?id=(?<id>\d+)(&(?<tail>.+))?$"`** means:

```
Match any string which starts with "/products/product.asp?"
optionally followed by string "func=show&"
followed by string "id="
followed by at least one digit
optionally followed by the next pattern:
   a string which starts with "&"
   followed by at least one character
followed by end line
```

So the question is how can I optionally use the "?" character in this replacement pattern

```
/product/${id}.asp?${tail}
```

near the tail group.

Comment: Do you have the option of just running a second regex afterwards to trim any trailing question marks?

Comment: no, I'm using it like this:

<add name="products_old" virtualUrl="...reg here..." destinationUrl="...pattern here..."/>

Comment: My only idea is to capture the original "?" with a lookahead that checks if you have more querystring that you don't want to chop. If you do, you match and capture the "?" and if you don't you don't match it and instead match it with a second non-greedy question mark. You then use the capture "?" to put in which will hopefully appear or not at will. The RegEx is a bit too complicated for me to want to try to get my head around but I hope this comment may inspire somebody else. :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Chris for your suggestion. I did a lookbehind for the "?". A "tail" is matched only when it has a prefix like "?" followed be any character. The original "?" is captured into a group also, so I can use it in replacements. When there is no "tail" the group in the prefix definition is not captured.

The regex is:

```
^/products/product\.asp\?(?:func=show&)?id=(?<id>\d+)((?<=(?<q>\?).*)&(?<tail>.+))?$
```

And the replacement is:

```
"/product/${id}.asp${q}${tail}"
```

The lookbehind is:

```
(?<=(?<q>\?).*)
```

Comment: Good stuff. I have to admit I had to actually check that before I believed it worked. I think the really clever bit there is capturing the `?` in the lookbehind. And just as a point you have an anonymous group captured that you can get rid of with `(?:(?<=(?<q>\?).*)&(?<tail>.+))`. I only mention it because you use `?:` already in there.

Answer (score 2):

How about having two regexps: one with `"id=(\d+)$"` and another with `"id=(\d+)&(.+)$"` ?

One would add no '?', the other would add it.

Comment: It would be a solution, I might choose it, waiting for other answers. The only problem is I don't want to duplicate this line... yet.

Comment: +1 These two rule regexes are mutually exclusive and will work correctly - there is no URL that will ever match both. What you are asking can't be done with a single rule.